# fluent custom plugin registration throws "Unknown output plugin"

Tags: ruby, openstack, fluentd

I am trying to modify an existing Fluentd plugin and use it with my customization. So I :

1. git cloned the plugin repo from github. `git clone <url>`
2. Edited my changes
3. **`gem build plugin.gemspec`**
4. **`gem install plugin.gem`**
5. Created a config mentioning the type of plugin
6. Ran **`fluentd -c <fluend_conf.conf> -vv`**

And I ended up getting this in fluentd log(**fluent-plugin-swift** is the plugin I edited and the type of the plugin is **'swift'**):

```
2017-03-22 15:00:27 +0000 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:126:block in configure: 
gem 'fluent-plugin-swift' version '0.0.1'

2017-03-22 15:00:27 +0000 [error]: fluent/supervisor.rb:369:rescue in
main_process: config error file="fluend_conf.conf" error="Unknown output plugin 
'swift'. Run 'gem search -rd fluent-plugin' to find plugins"
```

**EDIT-1: For clarifications**
I have also checked the naming convention of the plugin that is to be registered.
The plugin is present in `<base_dir>/lib/fluent/plugin/`. 
Also the name of file is `out_swift.rb`. And finally
 inside the file, the plugin gets registered as:

```
Fluent::Plugin.register_output('swift', self)
```

Also is there any way, I can check the list of registered plugins, and the name it uses to get registered to fluend?

**NOTE:**
  The same had previously worked for me, I had to re-do this as someone had formatted the machine I had my changes.

Please let me what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Did you try installing the plugin with "fluent-gem" ?

Comment: yes, I tried it previously and I had the same response with it... :/

Comment: is it possible for you to share the directory structure of the plugin, the plugin name mentioned while the plugin gets registered and the name of file should in format `<type>_<plugin_name>.rb`

Comment: good point, but I am aware of the name convention, I did check it, the file is present in `**<base_dir>/lib/fluent/plugin/**` and the file name is `out_swift.rb` and inside the file the registration is: `Fluent::Plugin.register_output('swift', self)`

Comment: okay, I am not sure what is wrong then, but add this info in the question

Comment: @Deepak is there any way, I can check the list of registered plugins, and the name it uses to get registered to fluend?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try this: http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/monitoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be with the installation path, Please check the following, :

Type **`gem environment`**

You will get to see the **INSTALLATION DIRECTORY** like:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.0 (2016-12-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
```

Go inside the **INSTALLATION DIRECTORY** directory, now do

```
cd gem/<ur_custom_plugin>
```

Now check whether, your files are there or not.
If not, you got your answer.

**SOLUTION:**
Simply copy your files to this directory and start fluentd

Answer (score 0):

As the above mentioned, this may related to which gem you used to install the plugin, for my case in CentOS7, the td-agent-gem as below works:

```
td-agent-gem install <pluginname>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install ruby development environment

   brew install rbenv
2. now run fluentD from ruby environment

   ~/.rbenv/shims/fluentd
3. this refers `/etc/fluent/fluent.conf`
4. Installing the plugin from ruby environment

   ~/.rbenv/shims/gem install fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter